# QGIS generates empty output using Clip

Tags: qgis, clip

I'm trying to use Clip in QGIS with a polygon layer (buffer of 5000 meters) as input and another layer as clip. However, the results are just empty with no attribute table and no image results.

I've succeeded with lesser buffers (20, 50, 200 meters etc.) but it seems like when I have a buffer that's quite large it doesn't work. The buffers are from about 18 000 points so it's heavy data too.

They have the same reference system and all, it worked as I said with lesser buffers but not for this one.

ArcMap error says "000117 : Warning empty output generated."

I also tried this in ArcMap but that just generates and error. I can't wrap my head around this, so hopefully someone can have some input.

Comment: Turn on-the-fly-reprojection **OFF**  and try again. If you want buffers in meters, the layer should have a projected CRS with meters as units.

Comment: The _input_ layer and _Clip_ layer should be in the same coordinate system.

Comment: In ArcMap, did you use the data management tools or Spatial Analyst Tools for clipping? You can also try the extraction tool if you haven't.

Comment: They have same CRS. I only use Qgis since ArcMap give me that error with no output. I use Clip (analysis) and in Qgis Clip. On-the-fly-reprojection was already off.

Comment: Perhaps one or both of your layers contain geometric errors? You can check their validity by using the **Check validity** tool or the **Geometry Checker** plugin.

Comment: I get some error, invalids but mostly valid outputs. How do I fix this then? ArcMap check geometry didn't provide any error messages.